# Loading / Saving HashMap<String, String> , HashSet<String>

Tags: java, bukkit

I would like to know how I can actually save and load the following HashMap and HashSet in the same file, /data.yml or /data.txt .. without them overwriting each other.

```
HashMap<String, String> teamByPlayer = new HashMap<String, String>();
HashSet<String> teamNames = new HashSet<String>();
HashSet<String> playersThatHaveDoneThis = new HashSet<String>();

String name = player.getName();
if (playersThatHaveDoneThis.contains(name)) {
//do stuff
} else {
// do stuff
playersThatHaveDoneThis.add(name);
}
```

This is what I've tried:

```
for (String str : plugin.getConfig().getKeys(true)) {
    int p = plugin.getConfig().getInt(str); 
    points.put(str, p); 
} 
plugin.saveConfig();
```

I want to know a way to save all those HashMap and HashSet ... Note: the example below is just for showing it.

Comment: What did you already try? Have you considered using the xml or json format to save your data?

Comment: I have tried saving it like   for (String str : plugin.getConfig().getKeys(true)) {
   int p = plugin.getConfig().getInt(str);
   points.put(str, p);
  }
  plugin.saveConfig();

Comment: please edit your question with this information.Please see [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote two methods for you:

```
public  static String convertHashMapToString(HashMap<String, String> h){
 String value = "";
 for(String s : h.keySet()){
  value += s + ":" + h.get(s) + ";";
 }
 return value;
}
public static HashMap<String, String> loadHashMapFromString(String saved){
 HashMap<String, String> value = new HashMap<String, String>();
 for(String s : saved.split(";")){
  value.put(s.split(":")[0], s.split(":")[1]);
 }
 return value;
}
```

I hope it works for you :)